# adding meta info in crawler and receiveing it in extractor

Tags: python, scrapy

I have separate crawler and extractor in python.

I want to store some information in meta of a request and when the crawl is complete, I want to receive it in extractor.

How can i do this? I tried

```
Request(url,meta={'fn':'Nadeem', 'ln':'Ali'}, callback=self.callback)
```

and in extractor, I used

```
mymeta = response.meta
```

But this doesn't get me that meta information.
Actually it does not write the meta in the meta file in my Cache director.

Comment: This `meta` will be available only in `callback`. Post some code.

Answer (score 0):

try `mymeta = response.request.meta['key-name']`